# How do space-filling parameter grids change when we call them by parsnip and recipe packages?

Tags: tidymodels, r-recipes, r-parsnip

According to this (https://dials.tidymodels.org/reference/grid_max_entropy.html) page, the output of a grid function may vary depending on whether we use a parameter object produced by `parsnip` and `recipes`, or we directly use a parameter object. However, **it is not clear** how one can obtain the parameter range if we use `parameters` object created from a model or recipe. For example, the default range of `neighbors()` is [1, 10]. When I use

```
myGrid <- grid_latin_hypercube(extract_parameter_set_dials(x), size = 25)
```

where `x` is a model, and obtain the range using

```
range(myGrid$neighbors)
```

I get some values for my `neighbors` that fall outside [1,10]. How can I obtain the default range of `neighbors` when I use a  `parameters` object created from a model or recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw in the documentation:

> the parsnip and recipe packages may override the default ranges for specific models and preprocessing steps. If the grid function uses a parameters object created from a model or recipe, the ranges may have different defaults (specific to those models)

You can see the ranges by looking at the `object` element of the parameter set object.

```r
library(tidymodels)

knn_spec <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune())

extract_parameter_set_dials(knn_spec)$object
#> [[1]]
#> # Nearest Neighbors (quantitative)
#> Range: [1, 15]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have also added an issue https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/725 so we can highlight these changes in the parsnip documentation directly